# Add layouts from templates using PyQGIS: the page orientation is not preserved

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

For each new QGIS project, I want to add a few layouts from prepared templates.

All templates are vertically oriented (A4 portrait). Inspecting the templates (the XML contents), I can see a `<LayoutItem>` with a proper `size="210,297,mm"`, as in this example:

```
<LayoutItem positionLock="false" zValue="0" frame="false" referencePoint="0" itemRotation="0" id="" size="210,297,mm" outlineWidthM="0.3,mm" positionOnPage="0,0,mm" position="0,0,mm" visibility="1" type="65638" frameJoinStyle="miter" opacity="1" background="true" blendMode="0" uuid="{3156912c-ce6e-4d02-8dfc-bc7c36b8f738}" templateUuid="{3156912c-ce6e-4d02-8dfc-bc7c36b8f738}" groupUuid="" excludeFromExports="0">
```

#### Adding templates manually

If I add the templates using the GUI, it works. The template is added and I get a new layout, with the correct page orientation, as expected.

[image: Add template using GUI]

#### Adding templates with PyQGIS

Since I want to add a few templates, I would like to add them using PyQGIS.

The minimal code is this:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

with open('/home/jgr/Templates/reserva.qpt') as f:
    template_content = f.read()
    doc = QDomDocument()
    doc.setContent(template_content)
    items, ok = layout.loadFromTemplate(doc, QgsReadWriteContext(), False)
    layout.setName('reserva')
    project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)
```

The layout is created **without the proper orientation**. The generated layout from the templates is horizontally oriented, but the template is vertically oriented.

[image: Add template using PyQGIS]

What am I missing in this PyQGIS script?

Answer (score 4):

`layout.initializeDefaults()` creates an almost empty layout. The generated layout has already one page, with the default orientation.

Setting `clearExisting = True` when calling `layout.loadFromTemplate` rewrites the default layout with the template's orientation. More info on the [loadFromTemplate documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayout.html?highlight=loadfromtemplate#qgis.core.QgsLayout.loadFromTemplate).

The entire code should be:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

with open('/home/jgr/Templates/reserva.qpt') as f:
    template_content = f.read()
    doc = QDomDocument()
    doc.setContent(template_content)
    items, ok = layout.loadFromTemplate(doc, QgsReadWriteContext(), True)
    layout.setName('reserva')
    project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)
```